# Should structs always be immutable?

Tags: c#

I was reading a couple of threads on here about structs and there is/was one about structs and how they should be representing immutable values (eg like a digit - 1) because of their value type behaviour/semantics.

But on the other hand, structs represent things like phone numbers, which can change for the same household.

Is this a hard and fast rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A phone number does not change; you just get a different one and discard the old one. The old one is still the same it always was. Same with dates, numbers, etc. - think of this when approaching structs. They are a way to encapsulate a value - which simply *is*; not the usage of the value, which changes.

Comment: If that's the logic then how about the following: We use a ticketing system at work, if a ticket is a struct, this will then have assignments within it (think of like an array in a struct). Once an array is written, it cannot be changed (or mutated) or even deleted, but you can add as many assignments in the assignments array as you like. I am thinking the ticket type should be a struct. However, I often think a struct should be the most atomic type (Eg in this case, assignment is within ticket so therefre assignment).

Comment: @dotnetdev Obviously usage various and there are exceptions to every rule, but I would not make a ticket a struct, because it is not a value, it is an entity with component parts that may change. Also important to keep in mind that a struct's total footprint should be no larger than 16 bytes!

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate there's no hard and fast rule but thinking of examples and asking other people's opinions makes me fine-tune my decision making processes!

Comment: Also, one other thing: It seems like the people who don't think about semantics of val/ref types and don't follow any of the factors in this thread seem to think that if your are storing a tightly-related set of fields (and just fields), you use a struct. Is this an incorrect way of thinking? (I seem to think so as many factors get ignored?).

Comment: @dotnetdev I agree, "related" alone is no criteria to use a struct. Classes are equally suited to the task of grouping bits of related information together. Structs are for a *highly* specific use case - namely, small values.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, structs should always be immutable! Mutable structs can cause terrible headaches as their usage can create very strange behavoir.

Comment: I think he's looking for an explanation of _why_ mutable structs are so bad.

Comment: Personally, I've never encountered such a headache with mutable structs and I've used them quite a bit (I think most structs in the XNA framework are mutable, like `Vector3`). I'm not sure if they're deserving of their infamous reputation.

Comment: Eric Lippert has one example: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, structs should almost always be immutable.  For example, in your phone number case, the phone number itself doesn't mutate: what happens is that the household is allocated a new phone number.  The phone number 555-555-1234 is still the phone number 555-555-1234, but the household's phone number is the *different* number 555-555-5678.

Note that you can find violations of this guideline in the .NET Framework.  For example, the WPF Point and Size structs are mutable.  This is not a good practice to follow, as one finds out when one tries to write `something.Location.X = newX`.

Answer (score 0):

Immutable value != Immutable variable

What I means is, even if your variable contains a *value* that can't be changed, you can still change your *variable* to have different contents.  `int x = 5; x++;` is legal.  `5++;` is not.

If your struct contains an integer, and you assign a new value to that integer (e.g. `myStruct.MyInt++`. you might think you are changing the value of MyInt.  Really, you're storing a *new value* that's one greater than the old value.

Why does it matter?  Because there might be another thread accessing myStruct.MyInt concurrently, and you don't want the value it's working with to suddenly change int the middle of being used.